# Sound, Videos stop playing after computer has been on for a bit

Tags: audio, video

When I turn my computer on, and go to YouTube, I can watch videos and play music.

However, after some time videos won't play anymore, and the sound completely fails. Even when I play local MP3 it doesn't work.

I have no idea where to begin looking for the problem. Any ideas?

I am using an HP Envy Dv6 with Windows 8.1

Comment: You don't even mention the operating system you use and what hardware.

Comment: @slhck I added the details. Hope you can unhold it